# Is the update order preserved in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb

If I trigger two updates which are just 1 nanosecond apart. Is it possible that the updates could be done out-of-order?  Say if the first update was more complex than the second.

I understand that MongoDB is eventually consistent, but I'm just not clear on whether or not the order of writes is preserved.

NB I am using a legacy system with an old version of MongoDB that doesn't have the newer transaction stuff

Answer (score 0):

In MongoDB, write operations are atomic on document level as every document in a collection is independent & individual on it's own. So when an operation is executing write on a document then the second operation has to wait until first one finishes writing to the document.

**From their docs :**

> a write operation is atomic on the level of a single document, even if
>   the operation modifies multiple embedded documents within a single
>   document.

**Ref :** [atomicity-in-mongodb](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/write-operations-atomicity/)

So when this can be an issue ? - On reads, This is when if your application is so ready heavy. As reads can happen during updates - if your read happened before update finishes then your app will see old data or in other case reading from secondary can also result in inconsistent data.

In general MongoDB is usually hosted as replica-set (A MongoDB is generally a set of atleast 3 servers/shards/nodes) in which writes has to definitely be targeted to primary shard & by default reads as well are targeted to primary shard  but if you overwrite read preference to read from Secondary shards to make primary free(maybe in general for app reporting), then you might see few to zero issues.

But why ? In general in background data gets sync'd from Primary to Secondary, if at any case this got delayed or not done by the time your application reads then you'll see the issue but chances can be low. Anyway all of this is until MongoDB version `4.0` - From `4.0` secondary read preference enabled apps will read from WiredTiger snapshot of data.

**Ref :** [replica-set-data-synchronization](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/replica-set-sync/#replica-set-data-synchronization)